# No module named 'cx_Freeze.util' ---cxFreeze in python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to use cxFreeze4.3.3(downloaded from sourceforge) in Ubuntu 32bits, where both python2 and python3.4 are installed.
At first I ran

```
python3.4 cxfreeze --help
```

And it printed help as wished.
Then I ran

```
python3.4 cxfreeze /home/lz/dev/test/interface.py
```

an exception raised:

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console
```

finally I specified the base name:

```
python3.4 cxfreeze --base-name=/home/lz/dev/test/interface.py /home/lz/dev/test/interface.py

File "cxfreeze", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/lz/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/main.py", line 188, in main
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "/home/lz/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 599, in Freeze
    import cx_Freeze.util
ImportError: No module named 'cx_Freeze.util'
```

After that I copied util.so from debian package.

```
ImportError: /home/lz/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/util.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

**Update**: I tried to compile util.so from util.c,an error raised:
Can't find "Python.h"

I replaced #include  with #include "python3.4/Python.h" or #include "python2.7/Python.h", but more error raised:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 21 has invalid symbol index 22
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o：In function‘_start’：
(.text+0x18)：‘main’ undefined reference
/tmp/ccMQ0pWq.o：In function‘ExtSetOptimizeFlag’：
util.c:(.text+0xa)：‘Py_OptimizeFlag’ undefined reference
util.c:(.text+0x1d)：‘PyArg_ParseTuple’ undefined reference
util.c:(.text+0x2d)：‘_Py_NoneStruct’ undefined reference
util.c:(.text+0x35)：‘_Py_NoneStruct’ undefined reference
util.c:(.text+0x3a)：‘_Py_NoneStruct’ undefined reference 
/tmp/ccMQ0pWq.o：In function ‘Module_Initialize’：
util.c:(.text+0x56)：‘PyModule_Create2’ undefined reference
Compiling failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since PyQt5 is only available in python3, I have to use python3, and cxFreeze is said to be the only tool that supports python3.
The cxFreeze debian package works well in python2.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Change the include back to just `python.h`, and make sure `python3-dev` is installed (from apt). You'll probably also need to make the change described in [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304) to get it to compile.

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks. python3-dev is installed, while #include "Python.h" or "python.h" still can't be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've solved this problem.Here are the steps:

1. Download cx_freeze source from http://sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_cx-freeze/downloads/4.3.3/cx_Freeze-4.3.3.tar.gz/ and extract files
2. Modify setup.py:line 79 to `if True:`
3. Run `sudo python3.4 setup.py install`
   And then everything works well.

Thanks for @TomasK

Comment: do you know why running setup.py build, then install as recommended by cx freeze would fail? should a bug report be submitted?

Comment: @Arden It's a known (and now fixed) [bug](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304)